# onclick is not working. whenever I submit it automatically executes all onclick handlers

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

Here is the code:
html+js

```
<input type="submit" onclick="chk();" />
function chk(){
var buttonnode= document.createElement('input');
buttonnode.onClick = ddiv(buttonnode);
}
```

`buttonnode.onclick` automatically calls `ddiv` function but I want it to wait for a click to proceed to that function. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below... it will give the result that you need...

```
<html>
<body>
<style>
.divstyle
{
border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
<script>

function myFunction()
{

var txt = document.getElementById("txtinfo");

//div Creation
var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
myDiv.setAttribute("class", "divstyle");
myDiv.innerHTML = "<br>" + txt.value + "<br>";

//Button Creation
var myButton = document.createElement("input");
myButton.type = "button";
myButton.value = "my button";
myDiv.appendChild(myButton);
document.body.appendChild(myDiv);
myButton.onclick = function (){ddiv(this,myDiv);};

}

function ddiv(btn, div)
{ 
div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
} 

</script>


<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<input type="text" value="Click the Below Button" id="txtinfo"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thats fantastic thanks Pandian it worked. really appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below... it will work..

```
buttonnode.onclick = function (){ddiv(this);};
```

Comment: now it is not automatically executing onclick. thats good but at same time its not calling ddiv function. now what?

Comment: function ddiv(div){
  div.style.background = "orange";
  div.parentNode.removeChild(buttonnode);
  
  }

Comment: all i want is when buttonnode is clicked it deletes the parent

Comment: you create INPUT element and you pass that as parameter but you use DIV in that function... i can't get your concept... Can you pls expalin the concept...

Comment: You want to Create a DIV and if we Click the DIV you need some actions right...?

Comment: i take input from text field and whenever i click sumbit a new div is created with javascript and the text from the input goes into that div. newly created div also has a button that is generated with div no if we have clicked submit 5 times. 5 div created with 5 buttons within them. now the button with each div is calling a funtion that destroys the div in which the button exists.

Comment: button inside a div .. when button is clicked div is destroyed.. bth div and button are being created using js

Comment: well thats very kind of you dear.. but kindly give me another favor.. whenever you click a button to remove div div + it content + button itself also removes at the same time.. kindly do this

Comment: bundle of Thanks i have been scratching my head for two days on this problem.